# Can git format patch so it can be used with patch program?

Tags: git, patch

I'd need to create simple patches from git repository that can be applied with plain simple patch command line utility.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Patches, that `git diff` yields, are correctly processed by `patch` tool.

`patch` skips all the additional info git appends to the patch file.  To apply the patch you most likely will need `-p1` option.

Comment: Patches generated by `git format-patch` are also correctly procesed by GNU patch... unless they are generated with -M / -C option and contain information about renames, etc.

Comment: From the `patch` man page: "patch  tries  to  skip any leading garbage, apply the diff, and then skip any trailing garbage." The big unique thing in git diffs is the addition of modelines (e.g. "index...", "rename...", "new file...") and patch is able to simply skip these. Git also prefixes filenames, e.g. "a/path/to/file", but this can be skipped by patch's -p1.

Comment: Is there a way to generate a patch that can be proceeded by 'patch -p0'?  I am applying my own patches to some program for macports but macports applies patches using -p0.

Comment: @icando, did you try `--no-prefix` option?

Comment: Thanks. The `--no-prefix` option did the trick. Otherwise default generated diffs are incompatible with `patch`.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer states the following:

> Patches, that git diff yields, are correctly processed by patch tool.

I'm pretty sure I just ran into a case where this is incorrect. `/usr/bin/patch` just silently (without reporting an error) ignored my patch including file rename information, thereby breaking a deployment (fortunately I'm only testing the deployment at the moment :-) ...

I'm posting this alternative answer as a heads up for other people running into the same problem because I was scratching my head for a while... Also comments to answers on StackOverflow apparently can't contain quotes.

Ironically enough I just now switched to the unified diff format to overcome this problem and now my deployment breaks in a different way because unified diffs can't represent the creation of empty files (e.g. `__init__.py`). Talk about being between a rock and a hard place!